# Need to pull out part of url

Tags: regex

Hello I need to pull out C0044SGXAU out of the url..

```
http://www.website.com/Sax-Mat-Rat-Mats-Cat/ce/C0044SGXAU/ref=sr_22?s=cats-rats&ie=UTF8&qid=5425444445&sr=1-1&keywords=animals
```

Results should be:

`C0044SGXAU`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
([^\/]+)\/[^\/]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following expression does the job for you (given the `/ce/` is always present)

```
^http.+\/ce\/(\w+)\/?
```

It works with and without the parameters - [See here](http://rubular.com/r/a0Tjtg9Bhg).